# What is this.module and when do we use it in Backbone.js application?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

Recently, I have started working on a project and in the code base I am finding lots of this.module statements (not this.model). As a beginner in backbone, I have no idea when should I use this and why? Any explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: `this.module` or `this.model`?

Comment: That's probably something specific to your code base. There are only two mentions of "module" in the current Backbone source code and they're both in comments.

Comment: @muistooshort that might be correct. I will talk to my UI lead then. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Might be something from Marionette too, I don't use Marionette but many Backbone people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules come from [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/)

> Marionette Modules allow you to create modular encapsulated logic.
>   They can be used to split apart large applications into multiple
>   files, and to build individual components of your app.

Here is a [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.module.html#Module%20Definitions)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. It inherits things from other classes so that we don't need to define/write the same things again and again.